# Using TLS on Google Talk XMPP TCP connection using PHP

Tags: php, sockets, xmpp, starttls

I am trying to connect to the Google Talk XMPP server using PHP. I am successful establishing a connection and logging in using X-OAUTH2. Then Google requires I establish a TLS connection. However when trying to upgrade the connection to TLS I get an exception: `stream_socket_enable_crypto(): Peer certificate CN='gmail.com' did not match expected CN='talk.google.com'`.

Here are my steps:

```
$stream = stream_socket_client('tcp://talk.google.com:5222', $error_num, $error_str);
// ... I login,
//server tells me to use TLS,
//I tell it I am going to,
//it tells me to proceed ...
stream_socket_enable_crypto($stream, true, STREAM_CRYPTO_METHOD_TLS_CLIENT);
```

And I get this error:

```
stream_socket_enable_crypto(): Peer certificate CN='gmail.com' did not match expected CN='talk.google.com'
```

Of course, if I try to connect to the xmpp server via `tcp://gmail.com` or `tcp://www.gmail.com`, it won't work.

I have also tried establishing the TLS before logging in (Which, I would assume is the more secure way of doing it), but I get the same problem. Here is the whole handshake up to the error:

```
Me:     <stream:stream to="gmail.com" xmlns:stream="http://etherx.jabber.org/streams" xmlns="jabber:client" version="1.0">

Google: <stream:stream from="gmail.com" id="7373AF2152849B51" version="1.0" xmlns:stream="http://etherx.jabber.org/streams" xmlns="jabber:client">
            <stream:features>
                <starttls xmlns="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-tls">
                    <required/>
                </starttls>
                <mechanisms xmlns="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-sasl">
                    <mechanism>X-OAUTH2</mechanism>
                    <mechanism>X-GOOGLE-TOKEN</mechanism>
                </mechanisms>
            </stream:features>

Me:     <auth xmlns="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-sasl" mechanism="X-OAUTH2" auth:service="oauth2" xmlns:auth="http://www.google.com/talk/protocol/auth">Encrypted user and pass</auth>

Google: <success xmlns="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-sasl"/>

Me:     <stream:stream to="gmail.com" xmlns:stream="http://etherx.jabber.org/streams" xmlns="jabber:client" version="1.0">

Google: <stream:stream from="gmail.com" id="B3A6AD05178A5BF2" version="1.0" xmlns:stream="http://etherx.jabber.org/streams" xmlns="jabber:client">
            <stream:features>
                <starttls xmlns="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-tls">
                    <required/>
                </starttls>
                <bind xmlns="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-bind"/>
                <session xmlns="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-session"/>
            </stream:features>

Me:     <starttls xmlns="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-tls"/>

Google: <proceed xmlns="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-tls"/>
```

Answer (score 2):

I haven't figured out how to fix the problem, but I could avoid it altogether by connection via tls from the get-go and using port 5223 instead:

```
stream_socket_client('tls://talk.google.com:5223', $error_num, $error_str);
```